# rails 3 setting table_name in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In mysql, i have a table named "socials", and my class likes below:
   When i create, it's have some errors.
   Any help much appreciated, my Rails version is 3.2.13, and Ruby is 1.9.3

```
   class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = "socials" 
     end

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: Table
    'pscrmdata.accounts' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO `socials`
   (`access_token`, `access_token_secret`, `account_name`)
```

Comment: i take a test in rails console, when i save Account, it's have some errors. like "activeRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'pscrmdata.accounts' doesn't exist:"

Comment: did you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: sorry, it's all my fault. I created a trigger in database, and the trigger executed a sql to accounts table, and i renamed the accounts table.